# How do I randomize the length of vertices in three.js meshes?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to randomize a mesh in three.js similar to [this](http://codepen.io/made-on-mars/pen/OXKqXJ) codepen I saw earlier today (the planets have kind of distorted/irregular edges). I tried reproducing this effect in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Maharkus/pen/bwPevO) I made (by blatantly copying a little code snippet from the codepen linked before) and changed the parameters to fit to mine (Look at line 56). As you can see the desired effect doesn't appear and breaks the code.

This is the part that won't work:

```
var noise = randomRange(1,5);
for(var i=0; i<Ico.vertices.length; i++){
      var v = Ico.vertices[i];
      v.x += -noise/2 + Math.random()*noise;
     v.y += -noise/2 + Math.random()*noise;
     v.z += -noise/2 + Math.random()*noise;
   };
```

Is there anything I didn't take into account here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: first off, `randomRange` function is not defined.

Comment: right, sorry about that, fixed it here http://codepen.io/Maharkus/pen/EgBNRz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you should approach your problem:

```
function randomRange(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

//Geometry

var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(25, 3);

var noise = randomRange(1,5);
for(var i=0; i<geometry.vertices.length; i++){
  var v = geometry.vertices[i];
  v.x += -noise/2 + Math.random()*noise;
  v.y += -noise/2 + Math.random()*noise;
  v.z += -noise/2 + Math.random()*noise;
};

//Meshes

var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, cyanMat);
Ico.rotation.z = 0.5;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(
new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(25,0), cyanMat);
Ico.rotation.z = 0.5;
```

put

```
function randomRange(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

var icoGeom = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(25,1);
var noise = randomRange(5,10);
console.log(icoGeom);
icoGeom.vertices.forEach(function(vertex){
  console.log(vertex);
  vertex.x += Math.random()*noise - noise/2;
  vertex.y += Math.random()*noise - noise/2;
  vertex.z += Math.random()*noise - noise/2;
});
```

and yes, you forgot to copy/paste the randomRange() function.

Comment: Yeah, I realized.. Thanks for your help!